# How can I show the leader's health of each team and make it say the other team won

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm making a Minecraft mini-game called "Clan Wars". You have to try to kill the other team's leader then you team wins! The problem is I would like the scoreboard to show the leaders' health and under both leaders' health, show all the players and the team they are on. When the leader is dead on the red side, for example, it says blue won and teleports all the players back to the lobby. If you need more information, comment below and I will edit those details in soon!

{I would rather it not be a pressure plate because a player can still activate it}

I have tried looking up testfor commands to do something like [testfor entity=ocelot x z y]
but it doesn't work

Comment: So.. what have you tried?

Comment: As with programming on SO, we do expect you to attempt to figure this out yourself before asking here.  Since that's exactly what this is, especially.  If you run into a problem down the line, we can certainly help, but Q&A works *much* better when you at least try to solve it yourself, first.

Comment: Also, I think you have to spell it Ozelot, not Ocelot.

Comment: @DatEpicCoderGuyWhoPrograms Yes you do.

Comment: We need to revoke people's ability to dislike on this site. This is a good, relevant, straightforward, and well-formatted question.

Comment: @Caleb It shows zero effort to solve the problem. As I've said before, we expect you to at least make an *attempt* to solve it yourself. Doing so will garner a way better reception.

Comment: @Frank on the contrary, it shows what he tried, that's why he came here. Like with my question, this is simply way out of his league.

Comment: @Caleb No, he has not shown *any* effort. Just, "here's what I want to do, how do I do it?" Showing what you've tried would be things like, "I tried using this command, but it doesn't work because X". Help us help you. Expecting us to do it for you with nothing on your end will result in down votes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming the leader is a player, not an entity.

Have a scoreboard objective of type `health` called whatever you want, and set the display to `sidebar`. Make sure the 2 teams have colored names. This will show health for everybody though. Also have an objective for death counts to keep track of when the leader dies.

COMMANDS:
`/scoreboard objectives add health health Health` - Make health objective
`/scoreboard objectives setdisplay health sidebar` - Set to sidebar
`/scoreboard teams add red Red` - Add team red
`/scoreboard teams add redleader Red` - Add team red's leader
`/scoreboard teams add blueleader Blue` - Add team blue's leader
`/scoreboard teams option red color red` - Set red name color to red
`/scoreboard teams option blue color blue` - Set blue name color to blue
`/scoreboard teams option redleader color red` - Set redleader name color to red
`/scoreboard teams option blueleader color red` - Set blueleader name color to blue

Then have a clock testing for a death.

COMMANDS:
`/scoreboard objectives add death deathCount Deaths` - Make deaths objective
`testfor @a[score_death_min=1,team=redleader]` - Output to whatever you want to happen when the red leader dies.
`testfor @a[score_death_min=1,team=blueleader]` - Output to whatever you want to happen when the blue leader dies.

Also don't forget to add all the people in the game to their teams!

Comment: Is an entity sorry forgot to say you can select ocelot or wolf

Comment: @kingbluesapphire If you are using the latest snapshot, you can just use @e instead of @p and add the entity using `/scoreboard teams join redleader @e[r=1,type=Ozelot] (or blueleader)` while standing on top of the ocelot.

Comment: Do you know how to set each teams spawn so if a red player dies then the respawn in reds base ans same for blue

Comment: `/spawnpoint @a[team=red] X Y Z` or any variation. The XYZ coords must be set to your current location, using `~ ~ ~` makes the game set spawn to be a few blocks off. Also adding `.0` to each coord makes the spawnpoint not average out, but always on that block.